# Warning message:invalid factor level, NA generated

Tags: r

I'm getting this error when I tried to assign new character value to some of the values in one of my columns.

This works fine:

```
merge_output$extra_dod[merge_output$extra_dod == 'Refugees camps in forestreserve.'] <-'Refugees'
```

but this doesn't:

```
merge_output$extra_dod[merge_output$extra_dod=='Air Strip'] <-'strip'
```

And it returns this error message:

```
Warning message:
  In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, merge_output$extra_dod == "Lime", value = c(5L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

I'm not sure why I can replace some of the values but not others.

Comment: You should provide an example so that you can be answered without us having to speculate. I am presuming extra_dog is a factor, and that 'dd' is not a level in this factor. You'll need to add it if you want them to merge

Comment: This works fine:merge_output$extra_dod[merge_output$extra_dod == 'Refugees camps in forest reserve.' ] <-'Refugees' but merge_output$extra_dod[merge_output$extra_dod=='Air Strip'] <-'strip' doesn't work.

Comment: what does `levels(merged_output$extra_dod)` return?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a much-simplified example that fails in the same way:

```
f <- factor(c("a","b","c","d"))
f[f=="d"] <- "e"
```

> Warning message:
>   In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, f == "d", value = "e") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated

If you happen to try replacing with a factor level that already 
exists, it works:

```
f[f=="c"] <- "b"
```

A few more general options:

- Convert the variable back into a character vector
  before trying to replace values (or use something like
  `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in `read.csv`/`read.table`)
- use `car::recode`